# Getting time eg 5 minutes ago

Tags: php, date, time

I have added a timestamp to my database so I have the exact time a post was made and now I would like it to say '5 minutes ago' or however long it has been.

Is there a php method for this or something or how would i do it?

Thanks

Comment: There's not a native function to do this which I'm aware of, but [this](https://gist.github.com/egza/3713606) should get you started.

Comment: Here is a function I wrote: http://phpsnips.com/snip-536#.UYLGWLWkrMg

Answer (score 1):

There is no native function to actually do this, so you will have to write a script...  This works for me:

PHP

```
function elapsedTime($time_since) {
    $time = time() - $time_since;
    $tokens = array (
        31536000 => 'year',
        2592000 => 'month',
        604800 => 'week',
        86400 => 'day',
        3600 => 'hour',
        60 => 'minute',
        1 => 'second'
    );
    foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
        if ($time < $unit) continue;
            $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
            return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
        }
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="answerTime">
    Asked <?= elapsedTime($time_since) /* YOUR TIME VARIABLE */ ?> ago by
</div>
```